# Pandas Fill consecutive null values with range of values between the first non null value before and after

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, ffill

I have a dataframe where I would like to fill null values in a dataframe following two conditions

**Condition 1:**  value after NaN `(in this example 10)` > value before NaN `(7.5)`

```
2.75
7.5
NaN
NaN
NaN
10
```

*Equally increments from 7.5 to 10. So it would be like*

```
2.75
7.5
8.125
8.75
9.375
10
```

**PS:** The increment is calculated as following `(10-7.5/4) = 0.625`

**Condition 2:** Value after NaN is < = value before Nan

```
2.75
10
NaN
NaN
NaN
7.5
```

*Forward fill NaN values*

```
2.75
10
10
10
10
7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting this to do for a series, you can use:

```
df['Col'].fillna(df['Col'].interpolate().cummax())
```

For a dataframe:

```
df.fillna(df.interpolate().cummax())
```

---

Showing for a dataframe for con1 and cond 2(*can be replicated for a series too*)

```
print(df1)

     Col   Col1
0   2.75   2.75
1   7.50  10.00
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    NaN
5  10.00   7.50
```

---

```
print(df1.fillna(df1.interpolate().cummax()))
      Col   Col1
0   2.750   2.75
1   7.500  10.00
2   8.125  10.00
3   8.750  10.00
4   9.375  10.00
5  10.000   7.50
```

Comment: This might work if you have one gap only. However, the problem is if you have, more NaN values, it will be filled with the maximum in the full series not the nearby value. Example: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2.75, 7.5, np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, np.NaN, 3, np.NaN, 5]})`. The last `np.NaN` value would be filled with 10 rather than 4

Comment: so I guess my question would be, is there a way around this by applying a certain window?